# Can't open VideoCapture in python

Tags: python, opencv, nonetype

I have this code that I downloaded from GitHub to use in an OpenCV project. Everything worked fine the first time, but after that it won't open, and it keeps showing me the following error at line 8:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hand.py", line 8, in <module>
    crop_img = img[100:300,100:300]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.rectangle(img,(300,300),(100,100),(0,255,0),0)
    crop_img = img[100:300,100:300]
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    value = (35, 35)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(grey, value, 0)
    _, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blurred, 127, 255,
                               cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imshow('Thresholded', thresh1)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE, \
            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    max_area = -1
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        cnt=contours[i]
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if(area>max_area):
            max_area=area
            ci=i
    cnt=contours[ci]
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(crop_img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),0)
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    drawing = np.zeros(crop_img.shape,np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),0)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing,[hull],0,(0,0,255),0)
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)
    count_defects = 0
    cv2.drawContours(thresh1, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
        start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
        end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
        far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
        a = math.sqrt((end[0] - start[0])**2 + (end[1] - start[1])**2)
        b = math.sqrt((far[0] - start[0])**2 + (far[1] - start[1])**2)
        c = math.sqrt((end[0] - far[0])**2 + (end[1] - far[1])**2)
        angle = math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2)/(2*b*c)) * 57
        if angle <= 90:
            count_defects += 1
            cv2.circle(crop_img,far,1,[0,0,255],-1)
        #dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt,far,True)
        cv2.line(crop_img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)
        #cv2.circle(crop_img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)
    if count_defects == 1:
        cv2.putText(img,"this is 2", (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 2)
    elif count_defects == 2:
        str = "this is 3 !!!"
        cv2.putText(img, str, (5,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 2)
    elif count_defects == 3:
        cv2.putText(img,"This is 4 :P", (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 2)
    elif count_defects == 4:
        cv2.putText(img,"this is 5 !!!", (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 2)
    else:
        cv2.putText(img,"this is 0 !!!", (50,50),\
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 2)
    #cv2.imshow('drawing', drawing)
    #cv2.imshow('end', crop_img)
    cv2.imshow('Gesture', img)
    all_img = np.hstack((drawing, crop_img))
    cv2.imshow('Contours', all_img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for people to answer your question, can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This will allow people to answer without having to peer through all the code you provided (and you may solve your problem while coming up with the example!).

Comment: didn't work , it works sometimes and somtimes no !!! why ? i use version 2.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution , it appears that some crappy video drivers return an invalid 1st frame. all i did is check ret and continue if it's false , it's working fine .

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that `cap.read` returned `None` to `img`. You should look out for that:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, img = cap.read()
  if not ret: break
```

The documentations say:

> If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer.

So if you are using a USB webcam, make sure that your USB connection is stable. In particular, if you are using any USB hubs/extensions or your port is in a bad shape.

Comment: i use my laptop camera , but why the code execute sometimes correctly and sometimes show this error ??